# How to delete row from UITableView using NSFetchedResultsController with NSPredicate?

Tags: uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

ViewController displays `UITableView` using NSFetchedResultsController to access `Core Data` (SQLite).  User can swipe and delete, added items are displayed.  All is as expected.

When `UISearchBar` is used to filter rows, it replaces the  `NSFetchedResultsController` with a new instance.  Same same except an `NSPredicate` representing the user input is set to `NSFetchRequest`

All is still good until user swipes to delete the row.  `commitEditingStyle` is raised and object is deleted. `didChangeObject` is raised and the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method is executed but this time the row is not removed.

Things start to go pear shaped after that.  If user attempts to delete row again, app throws

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
***`

So tableView believes there is no object at that index but it is visible, otherwise the user would not be able to raise the `commitEditingStyle` method.

**How do I get the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths to visually remove the row?**

Thanks Rob

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [moc deleteObject:objectToDelete];
        [moc save:nil];
        [self saveData];

    }
}


- (void) saveData
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [moc save:&error];
    if(kGlobalRunLogging && error) 
        NSLog(@"Failed to save data") ;
}

- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *) controller didChangeObject:(id) anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType) type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) newIndexPath 
{

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            //Boring cell formatting stuff
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
             [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
             break;

     }
 }
```

And finally the method that returns the NSFetchedResultsController

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsControllerWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *) aPredicate 
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

    [request setPredicate:aPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *namesDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"initial" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:namesDescriptor, nil]];

    NSString *cacheName = @"Root";
    if(aPredicate) cacheName = nil;

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"initial" cacheName:cacheName];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *anyError = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&anyError]) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@", anyError) ;
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController;

 }
```